# Getting an ajax value in a pop up

Tags: php, jquery, drupal

I have a link in my parent window with url and class as automodal. 
On click of the link I am passing an ajax request which returns a value. I want to show this value in the automodal pop up.
I have placed a div tag in the page that opens in a pop up and tried to append the return value to the div but it is not working.

any help???

Comment: why don't you call ajax from the popup?

Comment: You'll need to show us the script that you've already tried and explain what was wrong with it :)

Comment: How did you append the value? Show the code which appends the value to the div. have you used JQUERY to append the value? like $("#divname).html(value)

Comment: this is the code used to append the value '$("#customer_history").html(str); I am unable to get the result that I have returned in the pop up. I am able to get it in the parent window. What code should I write to get it in the pop up?